# Are these propositional formulas minimal, intuitionist or classical? And can you give some historical reference about them?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have faced a list with many well known formulas, but there are two of them which seem realy uncommon and rare, also there's no reference about who discovered them and they are nameless. The formulas are:

1. $((\alpha \to \beta) \to \gamma) \to (\delta \to ((\beta \to (\gamma \to \epsilon)) \to (\beta \to \epsilon))).$
2. $\epsilon \to ((\alpha \to \beta) \to ((\delta \to \alpha) \to (\beta \to \gamma)) \to (\alpha \to \gamma)).$

**A)** My first question is about the logical nature of the formulas: Are they minimal, intuitionist or clasical?

**B)** My second question is about the history of the formulas: Who discovered them? Is there any reference about them? Are they used in a specific system? Have you ever seen any of these formulas?

I'm currently trying to derivate them using the axiomatic method (Mendelson, *"Introduction to mathematical logic"*) and I would appreciate any information you can give me because that motivates me in the process of the derivation (I don't want derivations, just information).

Comment: Do you have a link for this list? The first has $\alpha$ and $\delta$ appearing only once. The second has $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ appearing only once. What makes these formulas special? Are they just random formulas? What axioms are you using for your proposed derivations?

Comment: Where did this PDF file come from? What is its source? I can not see your PC Desktop.

Comment: Thats the point, I don't know anything abut them. They are just there and they are rare. I'm using Axioms: 1) A → (B → A) - 2) (A → (B → C)) → ((A → B) → (A → C)) - 3) (¬B → ¬A) → ((¬B → A) → B)

Comment: It's a list of formulas and rules that my profesor gave me, I dont know where did he got it, and I don't know how to share it. I don't have a link from internet, I have the pdf only.

Comment: Ask your professor. He should know Please give examples of one or two of the **other** well known formulas for comparison. Also specify how a formula could be "minimal" or "intuitionist".

Comment: (α → β) → ((β → γ) → (α → γ)) -- (α → (β → γ)) → (β → (α → γ)) -- ((α → β) → α) → α -- (β → γ) → ((α → β) → (α → γ))

Answer (score 1):

Your first formula is
$$ ((\alpha \to \beta) \to \gamma) \to (\delta \to ((\beta \to (\gamma \to \epsilon)) \to (\beta \to \epsilon))). \tag{1} $$
It is of the form $\,A\to B.\,$ The only way for this to be false
is if $\,B\,$ is false and $\,A\,$ is true. Similar reasoning shows
that the only way for $\,B\,$ to be false is if $\,\beta,\delta\,$ are
true and $\,\gamma,\epsilon\,$ are false. But if $\,\beta\,$ is true
then $\,\alpha \to \beta\,$ is true and then $\,A\,$ is equal to
$\,\gamma\,$ which is false. Hence, equation $(1)$ can not be false.

The second formula is missing a pair of parentheses and should be
$$ \epsilon \to ((\alpha \to \beta) \to (((\delta \to \alpha) \to (\beta \to \gamma)) \to (\alpha \to \gamma))). \tag{2} $$
It is of the form $\,\epsilon\to A.\,$ An analysis of $\,A\,$
similar to that of the first formula shows that it is true and hence,
equation $(2)$ is true and thus the
$\,\epsilon\,$ is superfluous. It is certainly not minimal.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. The second formula is indeed  wrong, even in the list, I should have pay more attention. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @Maurocurto The choice is yours to make. I think that the question needs a bit more context. For B, even with well-known formulas it is hard to know when and where it **first** appeared, although it would be nice to know.